# Auto upload data into Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

Currently, I am building a tool for analytics with data from Google Cloud BigQuery with two steps as below:

Step 1 :  upload my file from local to Google Cloud Storage automatically first.

Step 2 :  load the data from Cloud Storage to BigQuery automatically.

I've done with step 2 in our code, but with step 1, I am trying to implement in Java, but I still don't find any useful info to do it.

Please tell me know if you have any useful information about this case.

Comment: the google cloud storage docs say: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload

Comment: Currently, I want to upload our file into cloud storage with Java code. what do you think about buiding java code in this case ? you have any tutorials ???

Comment: What do you mean by auto upload? Do I get it right that you have some data stored somewhere out of Google Cloud Platform and you wanna load the data into Cloud Storage on regular basis without user interaction? Then it would be helpful to provide where your data is stored.

Comment: Yes, I want to upload data from local ( my computer) to cloud storage without user interaction.

Comment: And what about a simple script based on gsutil tool that will push your data into GCS?